# Cannot register SIP on Android

Tags: android, asterisk, sip

I have Asterisk 14.4 installed on a server. I can register to it from Zoiper (PC). I am trying to register also on android with this:

```
String SERVER_DOMAIN = "ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com";
builder = new SipProfile.Builder(sipNumber, SERVER_DOMAIN);
        builder.setPassword("unsecurepassword");
        builder.setProtocol("UDP");
        builder.setOutboundProxy(SERVER_DOMAIN);
        builder.setPort(5060);
        builder.setAuthUserName(sipNumber);
        builder.setAutoRegistration(true);

mSipProfile = builder.build();
mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, listener);
```

and right after that I am trying to call to Zoiper (PC) with

```
 mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(),
                    toUriString,
                    listener,
                    0);
```

My problem is that I cannot register android (although I can register Zoiper and, consequently, call to it) but I can make a call. 
Here are SIP errors that I get:

```
registration not running -4
no data connection -10
```

No exceptions are fired.
What am I missing?

**UPD**

Probably this may help:

```
    <--- SIP read from UDP:93.123.41.227:48234 --->
    REGISTER sip:ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com SIP/2.0
    Call-ID: 65f42070f602eae50ac0ce5b64fe8fcb@192.168.1.102
    CSeq: 2170 REGISTER
    From: <sip:6002@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com>;tag=22509741
    To: <sip:6002@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com>
    Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.102:48234;branch=z9hG4bKe10ab1bfd8e1c98e91a14ba0d3b07d55383131;rport
    Max-Forwards: 70
    User-Agent: SIPAUA/0.1.001
    Contact: *
    Expires: 0
    Content-Length: 0

            <------------->
    --- (11 headers 0 lines) ---
            Sending to 93.123.41.227:48234 (NAT)
            Sending to 93.123.41.227:48234 (NAT)

            <--- Transmitting (NAT) to 93.123.41.227:48234 --->
    SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
    Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.102:48234;branch=z9hG4bKe10ab1bfd8e1c98e91a14ba0d3b07d55383131;received=93.123.41.227;rport=48234
    From: <sip:6002@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com>;tag=22509741
    To: <sip:6002@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com>;tag=as56c127e1
    Call-ID: 65f42070f602eae50ac0ce5b64fe8fcb@192.168.1.102
    CSeq: 2170 REGISTER
    Server: Asterisk PBX 14.4.0
    Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
    Supported: replaces, timer
    WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="607265aa"
    Content-Length: 0


            <------------>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to make it work. Surprisingly, if I pass listener to `SipManager#open(SipProfile, PendingIntent, SipRegistrationListener)`, then it does not register, but it does if I pass `null` as listener and use `SipManager#setRegistrationListener(String, SipRegistrationListener)`.

Plus, you can force registration with `SipManager#register(SipProfile, int, SipRegistrationListener)`, but again, it does not work for me if I pass non-null listener. Hope it'll help you

Comment: mate can you please explain little details please.

Comment: @Gurumoorthy Arumugam It didn't work if I put listener as a parameter of any method except `SipManager#setRegistrationListener(String, SipRegistrationListener)`: it just ain't called then

Also, I separated registration and opening connection with two separate methods, `SipManager#open(SipProfile, PendingIntent, SipRegistrationListener)` and `SipManager#register(SipProfile, int, SipRegistrationListener)` (in this specific order)

Comment: I too did the same but its not working in mobile data its working fine in wifi this is my code 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
            sipManager.open(sipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
            sipManager.setRegistrationListener(sipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {

Comment: @Gurumoorthy Arumugam please check NAT settings in Asterisk both in particular extension and in global. It is most probably somewhere there. Check also private IP of the phone in both networks and private network settings in Asterisk

Answer (score 0):

Your server setuped on Amazon EC2(from log).

Amazon EC2 is NAT'ed environment. You have hint asterisk about external ip using **externip=** in sip.conf

Comment: You're right, it's aws. But I tried both with `externip=` and without and it did not solve my problem. Moreover, I could connect from PC and couldn't from Android, which makes me believe that the problem was on client side